# Delete multiple sheet tabs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

In a Google Sheets spreadsheet (Excel terminology = workbook) is it possible to delete multiple tabs (Excel terminology = worksheet) in one go without having to right click each one and delete it.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

- **this deletes all sheets except `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`**

```
function DELETESHEETS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
     switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
     case "Sheet1":
     case "Sheet2":
     case "Sheet3":
     break;
     default:
     ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bulk Sheet Manager](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/bulk_sheet_manager/933437941260?pann=cwsdp&hl=en). It also allows you to hide sheets, which may be useful if sheets have some dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Created a macro, this deletes the first 10 sheets, modify as you need.

```
function DeleteSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();}
};
```